# Add a visual indication in the question list that a question is locked

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions

When a question is a duplicate, or on hold, you can see a sign, e.g. `[on hold]`, next to the title in the list of questions, so that you don't waste your time clicking on it unless you really want to.

When it is locked, however - which happens a lot due to the ongoing contest politics - I don't see a [locked] sign. It would be appropriate given that there is really no way to interact with a locked question, you can't even upvote comments.

---

**Edit**: one possible workaround would be to **actually put such questions on hold** - possibly on top of locking them. Yet you can't even vote to close a question that was locked, so it has to be done before or by a moderator.

I'm coming back to this because of [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83760/placing-rooks-on-a-chessboard): I'd long been thinking about it when I found out that it was locked.

Comment: That seems like a very reasonable question. I don't think it's Puzzling-specific, though -- isn't this behaviour consistent across all Stack Exchange sites? Perhaps it deserves a question on [SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It probably is, but I've never encountered such an amount of locked questions on another SE site (still relatively small, but somewhat significant).

Comment: That's a fair point. In any case, it's not something PSE mods have any control over; it's about how the underlying software works. If you think it would look better coming from a moderator, I can post a feature request over on SE meta -- it does seem like it would be an improvement. [EDITED to fix a typo.]

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I followed your advice [here on SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327588/add-a-visual-indication-in-the-question-list-that-a-question-is-locked). Apparently this is already a feature of the android app.